# Google Map JS Not Showing (tried other answers)

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, web, google-places-api

I'm working on a site that will use the Google Maps / Places APIs. I have verified that my API key is working fine, so that's not an issue. I just can't even get the map to display - that's my issue.
I've copied the example exactly, and it still won't work.
[**Here's my code**](https://gist.github.com/GitMazzone/ce1e27c1121fd3787eed282960b74144) in a gist because it's a few files. It should be runnable, that's all the content.

**What I've tried so far**:
- Putting it all in a document ready function (jQuery).
- Taking it out of the getCurrentPosition function so it was just out in the main.js file.
- Moving the position of the script link in my HTML file, nothing changed at any position.
- If I console.log() the lat and long variables, they print my location. But they're "undefined" when I type them into Chrome Dev Tools console. However, my "map" variable prints the map div to console.
- Using static coords, rather than coords gathered from the navigator HTML5 element.
- Setting height and width for the map div with pixels, percent, and vh/vw. It's taking the screen - I know because I gave it a background color that is showing.
- Added parameters to the end of my API load: `&callback=initialize&libraries=places`

This is my first time using Maps, so I'm totally lost here. I followed [Google's example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests) to a tee, and still nothing.

WebStorm is underlining all of the google.maps.x classes and saying they're "unresolved variables or types". That may be my problem, but I don't know what causes that or how to fix it. And to be clear, I have looked through every article I could find on Stack Overflow related to this, and haven't found a solution.

UPDATE:
- I just tried copying and pasting [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geolocation) from Google **exactly** as it appears (with my API key, of course), and it still didn't work. I put it in script tags in my HTML. The only way it works is if I delete the `initMap()` function - not the contents of it, just the declaration of it as a function. So why is the scope acting so weird here? It's treating everything inside of the function (which is in a script tag in my HTML) as if it's all undefined just because it's in a function... at the highest scope level.

Comment: `initialize` is not globally accessible. Take it out of `getCurrentPosition` callback

Comment: That was second on my list of things I've tried. I've also tried taking everything out and just setting static coordinates for it, no change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to run `main.js` before the Google Maps SDK has loaded.  Move it above `main.js' in`index.html`:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Then, remove the `initialize` function:

```
if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
console.log("Geolocation is enabled.");
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var long = position.coords.longitude;
    var map;
    var service;
    var infoWindow;

    console.log("lat: " + lat);

    //Initialize Google Map. Starts at user's location.

        var userLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: userLocation,
            zoom: 15
        });

        var request = {
            location: userLocation,
            radius: '500',
            types: ['store']
        };

        service = new google.maps.places.PlaceService(map);
        service.nearbySearch(request, callback);


    //Callback function for nearbySearch
    function callback(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var place = results[i];
                createMarker(results[i]);
            }
        }
    }
});
} else {
console.log("Geolocation is disabled.");
//Inform user why we use location
//Allow user to enter location manually
}
```

That works for me.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me as well. Why would Google show the initialization function if it breaks it?

Comment: The Google example only has the one function and it only triggers from the callback once the SDK has loaded.